# Django Form Date Input Field Not Showing Errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a form on a registration page that requires a date to be entered, along with a few other fields. If the user enters non-valid information into the date field (like a string) and submits the form, Django rejects the form as non-valid, but I don't get any error messages on the page - But for the other fields on the form, I do get error messages (ex: Passwords Don't Match, User Already Registered, etc).

Here is what the form looks like:
[Link to image of registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLWvE.png)

Here is my **forms.py** file - I'm using two classes to create the form on the registration page:

```py
from django import forms
from users.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        #fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("email",)
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    hireDate = forms.DateField(
        required=False,
        error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a valid date'},
        input_formats=[
            '%Y-%m-%d',  # '2006-10-25'
            '%m/%d/%Y',  # '10/25/2006'
            '%m/%d/%y'
        ])  # '10/25/06')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['hireDate', 'employeeNumber']
```

Here is the **models.py** field with the model for the profile:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #confirmed = models.BooleanField("Confirmed", default=False)

    hireDate = models.DateField(auto_now=False,
                                auto_now_add=False,
                                verbose_name='Date of Hire',
                                null=True)
    employeeNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                      verbose_name='Employee Number',
                                      null=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

And here is the **views.py** that presents the form - I'm combining two forms into one, and submitting with one button/input. The problem seems to lie with the second form (EmployeeForm), the first form (CustomUserCreationForm) seems to work fine:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, EmployeeForm
from users.models import User, Profile
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import messages  #import messages


def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, "users/dashboard.html")


#@login_required
# @transaction.atomic


def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CustomUserCreationForm(
                request.POST)  #, instance=request.user)
            e_form = EmployeeForm(
                request.POST)  #, instance=request.user.profile)
            if form.is_valid() and e_form.is_valid():

                user = form.save()
                user.refresh_from_db(
                )  # load the profile instance created by the signal
                e_form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance=user.profile)
                e_form.full_clean()
                e_form.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Your account has been approved!')
                return redirect('login')

        else:

            form = CustomUserCreationForm()
            e_form = EmployeeForm()
            print(form.errors)
            print(e_form.errors)

        context = {'form': form, 'e_form': e_form}

        return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)

    else:
        return redirect('dashboard')
```

And finally here is the html for the form on the **template** that presents the registration page - as you can see, I've tried a few different ways to get the form to present error messages, but none of them are working for the date field:

```html
                            <form class="text-center" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            
                            
                                <!--Username-->
                                <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required id="{{ field.id_username }}"</div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                   {% for error in form.username.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
                                  </div>

                                <!--Email-->
                                <div class="mb-3"></div>
                                <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required id="{{ field.id_email }}"</div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                   <!-- {% for error in form.register.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %} -->
                                </div>

                                <!--Password-->
                                <div class="mb-3"></div>
                                <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password1" autocomplete="password" required id="{{ field.id_password1 }}" placeholder="Password"></div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                   {% for error in form.password1.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
                                  </div>
                                <!--Password Confirm-->
                                <div class="mb-3"></div>
                                <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password2" autocomplete="password" required id="{{ field.id_password2 }}" placeholder="Confirm Password"></div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                  {% for error in form.password2.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                 <!--Date of Hire -->
                                <div class="mb-3"></div>
                                <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="hireDate" autocomplete="Date of Hire" required id="{{ field.id_hireDate }}" placeholder="Date of Hire"></div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                   {% for error in form.hireDate.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                
                                <!-- Employee Number -->
                                <div class="mb-3"></div>
                                <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="employeeNumber" autocomplete="Employee Number" required id="{{ field.id_employeeNumber }}" placeholder="Employee Number"></div>
                                <div class="text-danger">
                                   <!-- {% for error in form.register.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}-->
                                </div>

                                {{ form.non_field_errors }}

                                {% if form.errors %}
                                    {% for field in form %}
                                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                                            <p> {{ error }} </p>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %} 


                                <input class="btn btn-primary d-block w-100" type="submit" value="Register">
                                
                                

                            <div class="mb-3"></div>
                            <a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'login' %}">Back to Login</a>
                                
                            </form>
```

I'm not sure what else I can do to get the Form to offer error message to the user if the date is entered incorrectly.

Comment: Update: On the template page for the date field, I changed the form field type from 'text' to 'date' - this fixed the problem since it now renders the field as a date format only field with a date picker - no other type of input is possible. Would still appreciate any other comments on why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it is better to use `type='date'` instead of `type='text'` in input, but if you have used so, you can do it its validation from text also.

First thing the `hireDate` field is from `e_form` not <s>`form`</s>.

Try below code:

html file:

```html
 <!--Date of Hire -->
        <div class="mb-3"></div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{e_form.hireDate}}
        <div class="text-danger">
           {% for error in e_form.hireDate.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
        </div>
```

forms.py:

```py
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    hireDate = forms.DateField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Date'}),
        input_formats=(
            '%Y-%m-%d',  # '2006-10-25'
            '%m/%d/%Y',  # '10/25/2006'
            '%m/%d/%y'
        )
    )  # '10/25/06')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['hireDate', 'employeeNumber']
```

Now, you will see the error `enter a valid date` and setting `error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a valid date'}` to a `required=False` makes no sense.

The views.py can be remain same.